# "Could not convert varient of type (Null) into type (OleStr)" using a query component to extract data for later usage

Tags: delphi, variables, variable-assignment

I'm trying to extract data from the table "Games" using qry1 into a string variable to then insert it into "Library" afterwards. My problem is that when I click the button, it gives me the above mentioned error on the `sGameName := qry1['GameName'];` line. The field is a short string variable

```pascal
procedure TForm1.btnConfirmClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sGameID, sGameName, sPlatform : string;
begin
  if (chkAddLb.Checked = True) and (chkRemoveLb.Checked = False) then
  begin
    qry1.Close;
    qry1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Games WHERE GameName = "' + cbb1.Items.Text + '";';
    qry1.Open;
    qry1.First;
    sGameID := qry1['GameID'];
    sGameName := qry1['GameName'];
    sPlatform := qry1['Platform'];
    qry1.Close;
    qry1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO Library ([GameName],[GameID],[Platform],[UserID]) VALUES ("' + sGameName + '","' + sGameID + '","' + sPlatform + '","' + sLoggedInUser + '");';
    qry1.ExecSQL;
    qry1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Library WHERE UserID = "' + sLoggedInUser + '";';
    qry1.Open;
  end;
```

I expect the variable `sGameName` to be assigned the value in the column, but all that happens is the error pops up.

This only happens on that line so far.

Comment: What is likely to be happening is that the GameName column is empty, which is represented by the variant Null by qry1.  The logic is that since the column is Null, it can't be converted to a string,  you need to check whether the column contains Null before attempting to read its string value.

Comment: Take a look at: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.Variants.NullStrictConvert

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The issue**

Apparently this field returns `null`, indicating in general that it's empty.

A variant with value `null` cannot be assigned to a string like that. A small code to reproduce the issue without involving queries at all would look like this:

```
var
  s: String;
  v: Variant;
begin
  v := null;
  s := v;
  ShowMessage(s);
```

Note that some databases (Oracle in particular), don't distinguish between empty strings and null, so if you insert an empty string, you will get null back, because to them it's the same.

And it's quite weird that `GameName` is empty, since you used it in the `where` clause. That is probably because the game is not found and your query didn't return any rows. Check `qry1.IsEmpty` to check if you actually get a result before executing the rest of the code. That would probably solve your issue already...

**Solutions**

So, if you checked if the query actually returned a row, but some fields are actually null and you need to deal with that, there are two interchangeable ways to do that:

Use the `AsString` method of the field. For that you need to use the FieldByName method to get the field object, rather than it's variant value:

```
sGameName := qry1.FieldByName('GameName').AsString;
```

Or use the `VarToStr` function. The effect is the same, and I think this is more or less what AsString is doing anyway. Which one to use is a matter of personal preference.

```
sGameName := VarToStr(qry1['GameName']);
```

Comment: I just tried what you have suggested and it gave the same error, but the I changed `cbb1.Items.Text` to `cbb1.Text` after displaying the output in a show message that resulted in every item in `cbb1` to be displayed...
That's why it wasn't returning anything in the `qry1['GameName']`, or the table for that matter.

But what troubles me is that `qry1['GameID']` wasn't being flagged for error even though it was running into the same problem as `GameName`.

Comment: Good point about the Lines.Text. Didn't spot that one. Regarding GameId, maybe it's a different field type, which behaves differently? But also, quite often the cursor will be on the line after the one that gave the exception, so you might want to check again (maybe using a breakpoint and stepping through) which line it actually was.

Comment: Yea, makes sense. But all fields are short text in this table, so most likely that the error skips over into the next line.